# Does the use of AWS Mobile Hub + AWS Amplify will carry or rise problems with a HIPAA Audit process?

Tags: aws-mobilehub, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

Just a concern about using AWS Mobile Hub + AWS Amplify in order to make easier our tasks on the frontend side:

Does the use of AWS Mobile Hub + AWS Amplify will carry or rise problems with a HIPAA Audit process?

Thanks!

We don't see Mobile Hub listed as an eligible service here:

- https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/hipaa-eligible-services-reference/

ooooooor... is it just a tool that will help our app to securely configure and talk with a plethora of Amazon Web Services?

Answer (score 1):

Your are right, AWS Mobile Hub is just a tool that helps you to create and configure your AWS resources. And AWS Amplify is a SDK library that directly talks to the underlining services.